# cmd batch file for/f closes, comspec is already set

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

so ive been searching for the solution to this problem for awhile now, everywhere i look everyone just says "set the compsec to point to cmd"...which is super helpful cause no one actually even says how to do that.

but when i open cmd, and type "Set" and hit ENTER, it shows ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

I checked there and sure enough, cmd.exe is in there, it works just fine. But for/f still closes before performing any operation.

How do I fix this?

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('dir /b /s findstr "Find Me Testing"') do set    "AppPath=%%~b"
set "AppPath=%AppPath%"
echo %AppPath%


for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d ^| findstr "Find Me Testing"') do set "AppPath=%%~b"
set "AppPath=%AppPath%"
echo %AppPath%

pause

for /f "usebackq" %a in ('dir /b /s /a-d ^| findstr "To Be Deleted.me"') do set fileLocation=%~pa
echo %fileLocation%



pause
pause
stop
pause
wait 50
```

As you can see I've been testing various methods of doing what I want.

Comment: Without seeing the `for /f` command you're trying to run, it's impossible to say. It's very possible that the loop actually _should_ stop before doing anything.

Comment: Edit your question and post your batch file !

Comment: Not your current problem, but you need to use findstr's `/c` option to search for an entire string.  At the moment you're searching for anything that matches `Find`, `Me`, *or* `Testing`.

Comment: Also, depending on your exact needs, you might consider `for /R` rather than `for /F`, e.g., something like `for /R %%a in ("Find Me Testing") if exist %%a set "AppPath=%%a"`

Answer (score 2):

I lay good odds that your problem is with the cmd.exe autorun feature.

If you open a command session and enter `cmd /?`, then at about the 5th paragraph you will see the following:

```
If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
either or both are present, they are executed first.

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

        and/or

    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

I'd be willing to bet that one of those two registry settings is set to a command or script that is causing your problem. Edit your registry and remove those settings, and your problem should go away.

You can see a similar story about a user having trouble with FOR /F at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433.

The FOR /F command executes your commands within your IN('....') clause via a new cmd.exe process, and that process will always run any autorun setting that may be present. Unfortunately it is impossible to disable this FOR /F "feature" - I think this is a horrible design flaw.

Windows pipes also use child cmd.exe processes - one for each side of the pipe. But the pipe instantiation of cmd.exe includes the `/D` option, so autorun is disabled. You can see this by running the following command from the command line:

```
echo %^cmdcmdline% | findstr "^"
```

On my machine it produces the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" echo %cmdcmdline% "
```

Now do the equivalent with FOR /F (on a healthy machine)

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('echo %^cmdcmdline%') do @echo %a
```

My machine produces:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c echo %cmdcmdline%
```

No `/D` option :(